# Add a Filter Research depending on a list - mysql tab

Tags: php, html, mysql, filter

I'm working on a mysql table and I would like to add a filter research.

BUT... I want this filter be dependent on a list which shows every column of my table. So the user clicks on the list in order to select a specific column and then type what he wants to find in the filter research to find a specific value in this column.

I tried with a HTML list to take the value selected by the user and put it in my filter research but I failed.

I'd like to store the column choosen in variable_php and then use it in the filter research.In the code below, there is not connection between variable_php and my list.

I have also a second problem: when I click on the filter research with a empty input, I have this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must
> be of type mysqli_result, bool given in
> /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/myfile.php:226 Stack trace: #0
> /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/myfile.php(226): mysqli_fetch_array() #1
> {main} thrown in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/myfile.php on line 226

I don't understand because I have the `else{}` in order to display my all table in this case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <?php
    $variable_php=0;
    include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here

//Filter research
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE $variable_php = $valueToSearch";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Table2`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
?>

<body class="loggedin">
    
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    
    <label for="choice">Choose a column:</label>
    <select name="choice" id="id_choice">
    <option value="r_num_module">r_num_module</option>
    <option value="r_int_fen">r_int_fen</option>
    <option value="r_num_fen">r_num_fen</option>
    <option value="r_pk">r_pk</option>
    </select>

    <!--FILTRE--->
    <form action="myfile.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Search for a value">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter">
    </div>
    <br></br>

<table id="MyTable" class="table table-striped header-fixed">
<thead>

  <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><div class="cell-inner">id</div></th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><div class="cell-inner">r_num_module</div></th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><div class="cell-inner">r_int_fen</div></th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><div class="cell-inner">r_num_fen</div></th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><div class="cell-inner">r_pk</div></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="grid">

<?php
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
{
?>
    <th scope="row"><div class="cell-inner"><?php echo $data['id']; ?></div></th>
    <td><div class="cell-inner"><?php echo $data['r_num_module']; ?></div></td>
    <td><div class="cell-inner"><?php echo $data['r_int_fen']; ?></div></td>
    <td><div class="cell-inner"><?php echo $data['r_num_fen']; ?></div></td>
    <td><div class="cell-inner"><?php echo $data['r_pk']; ?></div></td>
  </tr>
  
<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
<?php 
mysqli_close($db); // Close connection 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding the mysqli_fetch_array error, that indicates your query failed for some reason (because mysqli_query returns `false` (which is a `bool`, obviously) when it fails, hopefully you already know that from [reading the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)! But to fix it, you need to find out exactly why it failed. Mysqli can tell you that, if you configure it properly - see [How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param/22662582#22662582)
 for guidance

Comment: `$variable_php=0;` You don't set `$variable_php` anywhere else, shouldn't that be updated with a value from user input?

Comment: You really should **not** be opening a new connection every time you run a query, that is really inefficient. Just open a connection once at the start of your script and then re-use it all the way through. It looks like you maybe are doing that in your `dbConn` file (although we don't know what's in it), but then in the filterTable function you're completely ignoring that and creating a brand new connection each and every time that function is called

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. Even if this is just your first test project, you should learn to do things the right way from the beginning.

Comment: And if you're allowing users to select which column to filter on, that cannot be parameterised so you need to create your own whitelist of acceptable values and check the user input against that before allowing it into the query, otherwise you'll still be vulnerable to injection attacks etc.

Comment: And, never configure your web app to login to the database as `root`. Root can do whatever it likes, so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: $variable_php is not set in this code because I can't find how to include it in my list.

Comment: Well you'd need to capture it from `$_POST["choice"]` to begin with...then follow my guidance above about whitelisting it before letting it anywhere near your query. Also remember that column names should preferably be surrounded by backticks in mysql.

Comment: P.S. `I don't understand because I have the else{} in order to display my all table in this case`...it won't go into the `else` just because you didn't enter a value. `if(isset($_POST['search']))` checks the value on your search button, which is always sent when the form is submitted, regardless of whether you entered any other data or not. If you want to check for blank values in the other inputs, then you'll need to add those to the isset() call.

Comment: Ok, I'll be more carefull about the "root", I'll check the error I got and I will try with $_POST['choice'], Thank you :)